# IF condition on temporary table takes long time for query execution

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT actualTable.column1, actualTable.column2, actualTable.column3
FROM table1 actualTable LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT column1, column2
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY column1
    ORDERBY ASC
) temp
WHERE IF(temp.column1 IS NOT NULL, temp.column1, actualTable.column1)
AND IF(temp.column2 IS NOT NULL, temp.column2, actualTable.column2)
GROUP BY actualTable.column1;
```

Above query is for reference. I have used 6 tables and added necessary joins.
The problem is that IF condition on Temporary table in Where cluase takes time. If i remove it then it takes less time to execute.

Comment: Give us the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE actualTable\G` (and for table2) - are actualTable.column1 and actualTable.column2 indexed?

Comment: Unrelated to the performance, are you sure the logic is valid?  `IF(temp.column1 IS NOT NULL, temp.column1, actualTable.column1)` is equivalent to the expression `(COALESCE(temp.column1,actualTable.column1) IS TRUE)` which seems like a somewhat unusual predicate, particularly when your result set does not contain any expression that evaluates to the same value.

Answer (score 2):

It is improper to "group by col1" but fetch col2 *unless* they col2 is either directly derivable from col1 or is an "aggregate".

The `ORDER BY` in the derived table will be ignored (once the two syntax errors are fixed).  Why do you have it?

`table2`, as the query stands, needs `INDEX(col1, col2)`.

Break the query up into two in order to avoid the `IF` clauses.  Something like

```
SELECT ... JOIN ...
UNION
SELECT ... LEFT JOIN WHERE temp.col1 IS NULL AND ...
```

That will need parens around it before doing the outer `GROUP BY`.